# Is it mandatory to create a DNS Entry for every New Web application created in SharePoint

Tags: web-application

I am new to sharepoint and trying to learn things

I have created a web application with name intranet and given in host header as intranet.testmachine.com
Created the web application successfully on port 80.

I want to understand is it mandatory to create the DNS Entry on Domain Controller now?
If so what is the purpose ?

Please forgive my ignorance.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the requirement and scope for the SharePoint environment.

1) If there are almost all users that will be using the site then you need to make an DNS entry to resolve the URL thoroughly.

2) If there are some users (like only developers) who would use the SharePoint, in this scenario you need to make a host file entry for URL instead of DNS entry.

So depending on the scope define the option which suites you.

Comment: Just to add - the purpose of DNS is for global resolution.  It serves the same purpose as a hosts file, it resolves a name to an IP (and vice versa if configured as such).

Comment: yes you are right.